# Correct syntax for finder path in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm in the process of modifying an Applescript script in Catalina. The script has this line:

```
set p2d to path to desktop as text
```

How do I change "desktop" to "/Users/[username]/[foldername]"?

I already tried:

```
set p2d to path to alias "/Users/[username]/[foldername]" as text
```

and

```
set p2d to path to "/Users/[username]/[foldername]" as text
```

but both didn't work. What is the correct syntax?

thanks, geb

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `path to desktop`, use: `path to home folder`, e.g.,:

```applescript
set foo to (path to home folder) & "foldername:" as text

tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window to folder foo
```